# DMX-Interface to use to write your own DMX-Control-Software

Tags: macos, interface, dmx512

I have a very specific problem: I want to write my own DMX-Software to control our DMX-fixtures. Does anyone know a interface to use? It would be great if there would be any Framework for using it, so that I only have to sent the channel and the value to the interface.

Comment: Do you still want to know this? I've just developed something like this myself, but it there are a few steps to getting it to work. You tagged iPhone and mac, which do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to! I tagged both because I wanted to cover the one option, where the DMX-Interface is controlled directly by the iPhone, and the other option, that a Mac controls the interface and the Mac is controlled by my Software for iPhone or iPad. The perfect solution would be a iPhone to DMX-Interface connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some really good information & code samples (including a working class that I wrote) here: [Lighting USB OpenDMX FTD2XX DMXking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905198/lighting-usb-opendmx-ftd2xx-help)

Ultimately, you end up setting byte values (between 0 and 255[FF] (brightest) in a byte array.
It's fairly trivial to implement simple effects such as fades or chases.

You would need to use a USB controller to convert your program's instructions to the actual hardware. 
I suggest using a simple iphone application talking to a webservice which then interacts with the hardware.

Code samples above are in c# though will show you how to interact with a DMX controller

Answer (score 3):

I noticed your question was for Mac, but I wrote a Windows specific C++ program, which could probably be easily modified. It's adapted from the C# example on Enttec's OpenUSB website. See:
https://github.com/chloelle/DMX_CPP