# DMX software to control lights with programmable interface

Tags: dmx512

I find myself in the need of a software to control lights with a programmable interface. Basically what I want to do is to automatically control the lights using some criteria that I programmed inside a program. My program will then control the lights passing through the software I'm searching for, of course this would need a programmable interface to which I should pass the commands to control the lights.

I've been searching for a software like that in the last couple of days without success, what I found are only softwares with GUIs for users, but no specification whatsoever about programming the light behavior instead of manipulating it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There's some really good information & code samples (including a working class that I wrote) here: [Lighting USB OpenDMX FTD2XX DMXking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905198/lighting-usb-opendmx-ftd2xx-help)

Ultimately, you end up setting byte values (between 0 and 255[FF] (brightest) in a byte array.
It's fairly trivial to implement simple effects such as fades or chases.

If you haven't got that far yet (e.g. up to the code) you'll need to get ahold of a USB DMX controller. 
There are a number of them out there, but the thread above has sample code for two different flavours.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted an environment where I could quickly write code that would create interesting effects for my DMX effect lights and lasers, and ended up creating it myself. I just announced the first public release of Afterglow, my free, open-source live-coding environment for light shows. You can find it at https://github.com/brunchboy/afterglow

Answer (score 0):

I needed precise control of individual mutli-channel (RGBAW) DMX512 lights and wanted to write code in C++ for Windows. I adapted the C# example from Enttec's website for OpenUSB and released the code:
https://github.com/chloelle/DMX_CPP